System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established in Integration Test
I have a console application with which I launch a battery of integration tests, to test my API in various scenarios (hhtp response scenarios 401, 400 and ok 200), locally no problem, but when I launch the pipeline on git some of the tests that verify that the status code is 200 or 204 fail for the following error:
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---&gt; System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ReadOnlySpan1 alert, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.&lt;SendCoreAsync&gt;g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean useAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.&lt;SendCoreAsync&gt;g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean useAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.&lt;SendAsync&gt;g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken) at User.Test.HttpService.HttpClientExtensions.PostAsync(HttpClient client, String requestUri, Object model) in /builds/projects/apis/services/apis/src/Services/Api.HttpService/Extension/HttpClientExtensions.cs:line 52 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.&lt;InvokeActionMethodAsync&gt;g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask1 actionResultValueTask)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails.ProblemDetailsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)`
I tried with postman to call the various endpoints and also the individual APIs called by mine and I never had any problems
And these bees also work correctly in the various portals/sites/applications that use them and therefore the problem seems to be only in the test application

"The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot" - are you using a self-signed certificate on your API?

In The Dockerfile there are this ARG ADDITIONAL_CA_CERT
RUN echo "$ADDITIONAL_CA_CERT" | base64 -d > /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/additional-ca-certificate.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates
